# Unable to cancel setInterval

Tags: javascript, timer

I am making a Javascript timed quiz with 10 questions to be answered in 60 seconds. It works fine if the contestant attempts the question in 50 to 60 seconds, but if he does it in a shorter time and restarts the quiz the timer runs at double the speed. Possibly the earlier timer isn't getting cleared. Here is the script:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#fblock').hide();
    $('#sblock').show();
    $('#qblock').hide();
    $('.startquiz').click(function() {
        qsi = 0;
        score = 0;
        showq(0);
        $('#fblock').hide();
        $('#sblock').hide();
        $('#qblock').show();

        var secs = 0;
        var id = setInterval(function() {
            secs++;
            console.log(secs);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML++;
            if (secs > 60) {
                clearInterval(id);
                $('#result').html(score);

                $('#qblock').hide();
                $('#fblock').show();
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('.restartquiz').click(function() {
        $('#fblock').hide();
        $('#sblock').show();
        $('#qblock').hide();
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: I've added the missing `});` at the end of the code, passed it through http://jsbeautifier.org, and marked it up correctly in the post above for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with edit while you formatted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like the only time the interval gets canceled is, when the "timer" (`secs`) actually exeeds the number of 60. 
The doubled speed could be explained by `secs++` which (after restarting the quiz) gets executed two times (once per started interval).

Try canceling the interval in the function that gets executed when pressing the `.restartquiz`-Button.

This could look like something like that (untested):

```
var interval = null;
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#fblock').hide();
    $('#sblock').show();
    $('#qblock').hide();
    $('.startquiz').click(function() {
        qsi = 0;
        score = 0;
        showq(0);
        $('#fblock').hide();
        $('#sblock').hide();
        $('#qblock').show();
        var secs = 0;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            secs++;
            console.log(secs);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML++;
            if (secs > 60) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                $('#result').html(score);

                $('#qblock').hide();
                $('#fblock').show();
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('.restartquiz').click(function() {
        $('#fblock').hide();
        $('#sblock').show();
        $('#qblock').hide();
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: Asking a question is not an answer. Instead of asking the question, provide the solution to cancel the interval timer. That's the whole point of this site...remedy code that isn't working as expected

Comment: Giving the hint, that his interval ist not beeing canceled as expected (because of the lack of an according command) is - in my opinion - the correct answer. This site is not about making someone else's work, but to provide the right idea so next time he or she knows where to look.

Comment: How many times have you searched this site to solve your own issues and found answers that were nothing but hints? The problem is clearly stated and OP is asking for help. If you aren't prepared to offer that help then don't answer

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution approach and changed my question to a statement.

Comment: removed my downvote...suggest reading through help center yourself to get a better idea of how site is intended to work